# RMR Architecture - At which point does it make sense to load the representation and headers?

Tags: php

I am currently in the process of developing an open source RMR framework. At the moment a resource representation is loaded and parsed in the resource itself like in the following example (this is at abstraction level and some parts cut out to shorten this post):

```
/**
 * Processes a given request and returns a response. Makes use of a 
 * data source for data retrieval and an array of parameters 
 * (usually passed in from the route).
 * 
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  mixed    $dataSource
 * @param  array    $parameters
 * @return Response
 */
public function processRequest(Request $request, $dataSource, array $parameters)
{
    $method = strtolower($request->getMethod());
    $this->dataSource = $dataSource;
    $this->parameters = $parameters;
    $this->request = $request;

    if(method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        // Something like get, post, head in resources
        $data = $this->$method();
        $response = new Response(StatusCode::HTTP_OK);

        if(empty($data))
        {
            // Do some stuff, return 200 ok no message-body etc.
        }

        // Find preferred media type in request accept
        $mediaType = $request->getMediaType();

        // .. loop through find representation  ..
        // Representation is reponsible for adding its own headers and body to
        // response, does this make sense to you?
        $representation->parse($response, $data);

        return $response;
    }
    else
    {
        return new Response(StatusCode::HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    }
}
```

So my question really is does it make sense to let the resource handle loading the representation of itself and then the representation setting response headers and body?

What would be your recommended approach?

Comment: Can be bad, can be good. It's hard to tell with the information you've provided. Maybe you want to offer multiple sorts of abstractions so both can be done with the framework?

Comment: Yes there are multiple representations of a resource and the most appropriate is loaded based on the HTTP accept header. To clarify does it make more sense for a resource itself to load the representation or leave that to the router, request or bootstrap?

Comment: Leave that to a `RepresentationResolver` which operates on `Request`, `Response` and `Resource`. Keep classes small and distinct.

Comment: Ah I can't believe I didn't think of something like that. If you can please provide your comment as an actual answer with a small example I can upvote and mark your's as the solution. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave that to a `RepresentationResolver` which operates on Request, Response and Resource. Keep classes small and distinct.

```
interface RepresentationResolver
{
    /**
     * @return Representation
     */
    public function resolve();
}

class DataRepresentationResolver implements RepresentationResolver
{
    public function __construct(your arguments)
    {

    }
    public function resolve()
    {
        ...
        $representation = $this->getRepresentation($this->data);
    }
}
```

Then when you compile the response:

```
$resolver = new DataRepresentationResolver(your arguments);
$representation = $resolver->resolve();
$representation->parse($response, $data);
```

You can then code any type or `RepresentationResolver` you see fit, even families of such, e.g. working with a specific request type or for specific sort of media type you specify (e.g. by mime-type).

Comment: Related [answer(s) in Question *OOP (beneficial usage)*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10388669/367456)