# OOP (beneficial usage)

Tags: php, oop

for my question on **how to use OOP in a beneficial way** I assume as an example a BASKET to which its owner (Tom) having a certain ADDRESS (NY) can add ARTICLES (Bike, Car). Finally a BILL is printed containg all these information.

My problem is: How to handle collecting the information desired (here: owner, city, amount of items) from several objects? Because I think it is stupid to do this manually as done below (see 4.), isn't it? (even more since the amount of information increases in reality)

So what is the "clean way" for creating the bill / collecting the information needed in this example?

```
<?php
$a = new basket('Tom','NY');
$a->add_item("Bike",1.99);
$a->add_item("Car",2.99);

$b = new bill( $a );
$b->do_print();
```

1.

```
class basket {

    private $owner = "";
    private $addr = "";
    private $articles = array();

    function basket( $name, $city ) {
        // Constructor
        $this->owner = $name;
        $this->addr = new addresse( $city );

    }

    function add_item( $name, $price ) {
        $this->articles[] = new article( $name, $price );
    }

    function item_count() {
        return count($this->articles);
    }

    function get_owner() {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    function get_addr() {
        return $this->addr;
    }

}
```

2.

```
class addresse {

    private $city;

    function addresse( $city ) {
        // Constructor
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    function get_city() {
        return $this->city;
    }

}
```

3.

```
class article {

    private $name = "";
    private $price = "";

    function article( $n, $p ) {
        // Constructor
        $this->name = $n;
        $this->price = $p;
    }   

}
```

4.

```
class bill {

    private $recipient = "";
    private $city = "";
    private $amount = "";

    function bill( $basket_object ) {

        $this->recipient = $basket_object->get_owner();
        $this->city = $basket_object->get_addr()->get_city();
        $this->amount = $basket_object->item_count();

    }

    function do_print () {
        echo "Bill for " . $this->recipient . " living in " . $this->city . " for a total of " . $this->amount . " Items.";
    }

}
```

Comment: The bill doesn't really need to be a separate class, since all the information you're gathering is already in the basket object. You could just add a `print_bill()` function to the basket.

Comment: @Lion - can you outline your objection to Basket? Someone else thinks the same as you (you have a +ve flag next to your comment) but it's not clear to me why that couldn't be an object.

Comment: @Tom - a quick tip. Since you're working with objects, PHP lets you strongly type your function object parameters, which in turn helps to reduce your bug count. Instead of `function bill( $basket_object )` do `function __construct( Basket $basket_object )`. You can see there that I've changed the name of your constructor (your approach is deprecated) and I think camel-case is generally recommended for class names too.

Comment: @Justin: Okay, but nevertheless in this example I have to get the city-value from the ADDRESS-Object "manually"? And in a "real-application-scenario" there would be even much more information. So is it actually a clean way collecting all these information manually?

Comment: (My comments are an aside - not an answer to the question. Hopefully helpful!).

Comment: @Tom: It's not manually, it's just coded. As this has more than a single name addressing the specific (sub-) values, it turns out that it's more complicated than printing a single string.

Answer (score 2):

If you do [Tell Dont Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask), you would indeed add a render method to the bill to which you would pass an instance of BillRenderer. Bill would then tell BillRenderer how to render the Bill. This is in accordance with [InformationExpert and High Cohesion principles](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29) that suggest methods to be on the objects with the most information to fulfill the task.

```
class Bill
{
    …
    public function renderAs(BillRenderer $billRenderer)
    {
        $billRenderer->setRecipient($this->owner);
        $billRenderer->setAddress($this->address);
        …
        return $billRenderer->render();
    }
}
```

BillRenderer (an interface) would then know the output format, e.g. you'd write concrete renderers for PlainText or HTML or PDF:

```
class TxtBillRenderer implements BillRenderer
{
    …
    public function render()
    {
        return sprintf('Invoice for %s, %s', $this->name, $this->address);
    }
}

echo $bill->renderAs(new TxtBillRenderer);
```

If your Bill contains other objects, those would implement a renderAs method as well. The Bill would then pass the renderer down to these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Both basket as well as bill could have a relation to a positions item - an object representing an ordered list of zero or more items with a count and price.

As such a list is an object of it's own it's easy to pass around:

```
$bill = new Bill($buyer, $address, $basket->getPositions());
```

However the printing of the bill should be done by the `BillPrinter`, because it's not the job of the bill to print itself:

```
$billPrinter = new BillPrinter($bill, $printerDevice);
$billPrinter->print();
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't address be a property of $buyer? Or is there  functional reason why an address requires its own object?

Comment: @Malovich: Often next to the buyer, a bill can have an additional address (the address where the bill is sent to, but that is not the buyer's address, the person/legal entity the bill is for).

Comment: So here the Bill-Constructor would collect all information needed from the $buyer-, $address-, and each item-object? There is no way around it?

Comment: @hakre: That would make sense for when third-party purchases are available- still, tracking both billing and shipping addresses would still resolve to the individual account, wouldn't it? Mmm. This isn't a simple thing, is it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all , in PHP5 the constructor it `public function __construct()`. What you are using there is the PHP4 way. And then ther eare other issues with your code:

- instead of passing the **name** of the city to the `Basket` ( do you mean `Cart` ?), you should be creating the address object instance and passing it.
- do not add items based on name an amount of money to the basket, instead add the whole instance of item, otherwise you will have a lot of problems when switching site language or currency.
- the `Articles` (do you mean `Items` ?) should be created based on ID, not based on name. The reasons for that are the same as above + you will have issues with uniqueness. And then some of items might have lower price, when bought in combination. You need a way to safely identify them.

As for cleaning up the code there:

- you should stop creating instance from given parameters in the constructor. While it is not always a bad thing, in your case you are making a mess there.
- `Bill` should not be responsible for printing itself.

Something like :

```
class Basket
{
    // -- other code 

    public function handleInvoice( Bill $invoice )
    {
        $invoice->chargeFor( $this->items );
        $invoice->chargeTo( $this->account );
        return $invoice->process();
    }
}
```

.. then use it as

```
$cart = new Basket(..);
// some operation with it

$invoice = new Bill;
$cart->handleInvoice($invoice);

$printer = new PDFPrinter;
// OR new JpegPrinter; OR new FakePrinter OR anything else
$printer->print( $invoice );
```

This would give you an instance of `Bill` outside the class which then you can either print or send to someone.

Also , you might benefit from watching the willowing lecture:

- [Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc)
- [Don't Look For Things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)
- [Clean Code I: Arguments](http://vimeo.com/13439458)