# OOP - without GET / SET

Tags: php, oop

Following the ["Tell, don't Ask"-principle](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) one should not use getters in OOP.

But how to solve problems where (at least I think so) one actually need some "inside information" from an object? So how to change the following example so that the  create_bill() function does not need to ASK for the price for each item?

```
class chopping_cart {

    private $itemlist = array();

    function item_add( $name, $price ) {
        $his->itemlist[]=new item( $name, $price );
    }
    private create_bill() {

        foreach $this->itemlist AS $element;
        $sum += $element->get_price();

    }
}


class item {
    private $name;
    private $price;
    function __construcor($name,$price) {...}
    function get_price() {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$sc = new shopping_cart()
$sc->item_add( "Bike", 1.00 );
$sc->item_add( "Ship", 2.00 );
$sc->create_bill();
```

Comment: if a shopping cart contains alist of items, why is it bad to have the shopping cart be able to learn the value of the price of each item?

Comment: following the stated "Tell don't Ask"-principle it seems to be evil.

Comment: Where did you hear this "tell don't ask" principle? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @xxpor try to use Google, man :)

Comment: Strongly related to the OP's previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387889/oop-beneficial-usage (which will provide a source for Tell Don't Ask). I suspect this should have been a continuation of that question.

Comment: Thank you for this question - it gave some knowledge into my head.

Comment: @OZ_ Yeah, should have thought of that...

Comment: @Tom if you're happy with one of the answers given, please accept them to help others find what worked for you. If you need more answers, do add comments.

Answer (score 7):

If you're not using the requested data/state to change the object you're referring to, I don't think there's anything wrong with using getters at all.

The principle talks about a scenario like this:

```
if ($item->get_price() < 5) {
    $item->set_price(5);
}
```

That should be turned into something like `$item->set_minimum_price(5)`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two items from the "[Tell, Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)" article you're referring to that bear close examination:

1. > [...] do not ask [objects] questions about their state, make a decision, and then tell them what to do.

   With your particular example, `chopping_cart` only queries the objects & makes a decision. Crucially, it doesn't go on to tell them what to do.
2. > According to Design by Contract, as long as your methods (queries and commands ) can be freely intermixed, and there is no way to violate the class invariant by doing so, then you are ok. But while you are maintaining the class invariant, you may have also dramatically increased the coupling between the caller and the callee depending on how much state you have exposed.

   Getter calls can generally be freely intermixed, so there's no coupling caused by the need to maintain class invariants.

Thus, getters don't cause the issues that the "tell, don't ask" principle is supposed to prevent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in this case. In your `Product` class implement the method `addToBill` and as argument pass an instance that implements your bill interface, `IBill`. `IBill` supports a method `addToTotal` which will accept all the needed information available in the item; in your case, this is a price. For example:

```
interface IBill {
    /* needs to be public because PHP doesn't understand the concept of 
       friendship
     */
    function addToTotal($price);
}

class Bill implements IBill {
    private $total = 0;

    function addToTotal($price) {
        $this->total += $price;
    }
    ...
}

class ShoppingCart {
    private $items = array();

    function addItem($id, $product, $quantity) {
        if (isset($this->items[$id])) {
            $this->items[$id]->addQuantity($quantity);
        } else {
            $this->items[$id] = new LineItem($product, $quantity);
        }
    }

    private createBill() {
        $bill = new Bill;
        foreach ($this->items AS $lineItem) {
            $lineItem->addToBill($bill);
        }
        return ...;
    }
}

class LineItem {
    private $product, $quantity;
    function __constructor($product, $quantity) {...}
    function addToBill(IBill $bill) {
        $this->product->addToBill($bill, $quantity);
    }
    function addQuantity($quantity) {
        $this->quantity += $quantity;
    }
    ...
}

class Product {
    private $name, $description, $price;
    function __constructor(...) {...}
    function addToBill(IBill $bill, $quantity) {
        $bill->addToTotal($this->price * $quantity);
    }
    ...
}
```

However, you'll always wind up on shaky ground. The above requires a method like `addToTotal`, which introduces an invariant (the total must match the sum of the products of the line item prices and quantities), just the sort of thing "Tell, Don't Ask" is supposed to avoid. You can try to do it without `addToTotal`:
* Do away with `Bill`; `ShoppingCart` keeps track of the total. Pass the price to `addItem` in addition to the product & quantity; `addItem` updates the total. This somewhat defeats the purpose of having classes, as you aren't using `LineItem` or `Product` for much. This also adds an invariant that the passed price and the price given when the product was created should match, though if they don't, it shouldn't cause issues (it would just be weird).
* Have `addItem` instantiate the `Product` and `LineItem`; `addItem` updates the total. When adding additional items that were previously added, there must either be an additional invariant that the passed-in `$price` must match the amount passed in previous calls, or `addItem` simply can't be allowed to add additional, existing items.
* Do away with items all together. `ShoppingCart` stores the product ID and quantity. Each call to `addItem` updates the total. `createBill` uses the already calculated total. Even more than the others, this unites [separate concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

There are other potential designs, but every one suffers from some sort of issue, typically relating to separation of concerns, introducing invariants and adding complexity. All-together, accessing a line item's total price directly within the method that calculates the total is not only the simplest, but cleanest and least likely to produce errors.