# Executing constructor yes/no

Tags: php, oop

Assuming as in [OOP (beneficial usage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387889/oop-beneficial-usage) that I want to create a bill for the items on a shopping card I pass a Bill-object to the basket's handleInvoice()-function (all is written in PHP):

```
class Basket {
    // -- other code 

    public function handleInvoice( Bill $invoice ) {
        $invoice->chargeFor( $this->items );
        $invoice->chargeTo( $this->account );
        return $invoice->process();
    }
}
```

Here no constructor is needed in the Bill-class, since no billing data exists so far.

But if I want to use the same Bill class also for managing earlier invoices I need some constructor loading all the billing data from database:

```
class Bill {
    private $date;
    // --- other stuff

    function __construct( $bill_id ) {

        $result = mysql( "select * from invoices where id = $bill_id" );
        $this->date = $result['date'];
        // --- other stuff

    }

}
```

How can I "tell" the program now that in the former case the constructor should not be executed while in the later it should?

Comment: It is possible to have two different constructors.  One that takes in a `$bill_id` and one that does not.  If there is no $bill_id argument for the constructor you know there is no data yet, and it will use the `function __construct ()`, if there is a $bill_id argument it will use `function __construct( $bill_id )`

Comment: or you can add a simple condition in constructor

Comment: unfortunately this is not possible in PHP...

Comment: Ha yes of course, too many languages in my brain and PHP is not a recent one :-p

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the conditional `__construct` camp.

```
public class Bill {

    public function __construct( $bill_id = '' ){
        if (!empty($bill_id)) {
            $result = ...
        } 
    }
}
```

The factory pattern works as well; you just can't get lazy with calling `new Bill` whenever you want one. You'll need to call the method specific to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support constructor overloading. So You can use "Factory Pattern".

```
public class Bill(){

  private function __construct(){
    //prevent new Bill() called from outside the class
  }

  public static function createEmptyBill(){
    return new Bill();
  }

  public static function createBillFromData($bill_id){
    $bill = new Bill();
    //assign any var..
    return $bill;
  }
}
```

Comment: Having a private constructor is not singleton. pattern above allow you to create more than one instant. calling `Bill::createEmptyBill();` 10 time then you got 10 instant.

Comment: but you will always have one "instance" of class Bill and it will bring hidden dependency to all your code, where Bill:: will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor should only initialize variables, and shouldn't do any "real work".
Because all methods from interface of class should be testable, and constructor should not be declared in interface (or this interface will be useless).
More information:
http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/